# Pandas pivoting multiple columns around a single column

Tags: python, pandas

Im trying to turn this

```
    iVWAPBucket  Side  NotionalTraded
0  -10 - -5 bps   Buy        0.079994
1  -2.5 - 0 bps   Buy        0.031706
2   0 - 2.5 bps   Buy        0.138434
3   10 - 25 bps   Buy        0.296976
4   2.5 - 5 bps   Buy        0.078794
5   2.5 - 5 bps  Sell        0.292118
6    5 - 10 bps   Buy        0.081977
```

into this

```
    iVWAPBucket     Buy         Sell
0  -10 - -5 bps     0.079994    -    
1  -2.5 - 0 bps     0.031706    -   
2   0 - 2.5 bps     0.138434    -   
3   10 - 25 bps     0.296976    -   
4   2.5 - 5 bps     0.078794    -   
5   2.5 - 5 bps     -           0.292118
6    5 - 10 bps     0.081977    -
```

What is the most efficient way of doing this?
I can do a single column like this, but can with multiple

```
primary_breakdown_table.pivot(index=primary_breakdown_table.index, columns='Side')['NotionalTraded']
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pivot a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe)

Comment: `df.pivot('iVWAPBucket','Side','NotionalTraded').reset_index()`

Answer (score 0):

use `pivot_table()` as follows:

```
df2 = df.pivot_table(
    values='NotionalTraded',
    columns=['Side'],
    index=['iVWAPBucket','Side']
    ).reset_index().drop(columns=['Side'])

df2.columns.rename(None, inplace=True)
```

output

```
    iVWAPBucket       Buy      Sell
0  -10 - -5 bps  0.079994       NaN
1  -2.5 - 0 bps  0.031706       NaN
2   0 - 2.5 bps  0.138434       NaN
3   10 - 25 bps  0.296976       NaN
4   2.5 - 5 bps  0.078794       NaN
5   2.5 - 5 bps       NaN  0.292118
6    5 - 10 bps  0.081977       NaN
```